# Change log level of yarn?

Tags: apache-hadoop

I'd like to change the log level of yarn. For example, when I run `yarn node -list`, I see a line that says `INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to Resource Manager...`. I don't want to see that. Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
yarn --help | grep loglevel
```

Or:

```
yarn app -list 2> /dev/null | grep -iv info
```

Personally, I had -verbose:class in hadoop-env.sh YARN_OPTS generating info class load output.